# Duda bash script. Recorrer un directorio con bucle for y contar los archivos de éste

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

estoy haciendo un programa que me pide mostrar un menú con las siguientes opciones:

```
#!/bin/bash
#p3ejer6
#Eco del nombre ficheros ordinarios del directorio actual
#Número de ficheros que hay en el directorio actual
#Con bucles for

echo "¿Qué ficheros o cuántos ficheros en el directorio actual?"
echo
echo "1: Muestra el eco del nombre de todos los ficheros ordinarios que haya en el directorio actual"
echo
echo "2: Cuenta los ficheros que hay en el directorio actual"
echo
echo "3: Sale."
read op


case $op in
        1 )
            for fichero in $(ls); do
                if [[ -f $fichero ]]; then
                    echo $fichero
                fi
            done
        ;;

        2 ) 
            
            for fichero in $(ls); do
                if [[ -f $fichero ]]; then
                    echo $fichero | wc -l
                    
                fi
            done
        ;;

        3 )
            echo "Saliendo..."
            exit 1
        ;;

        * )
            echo "Opción introducida incorrecta"
            exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Mi duda está en que ahora mismo no sé cómo contar las líneas de la segunda opción, como lo tengo que realizar con un bucle for pues me imprime 1 1 1 1 1 (para abajo). He intentado meterlo en una variable pero me sale error. Y debe hacerse con for sí o sí.

El enunciado es tal y como pongo en los comentarios, la primera opción me sale pero no sé si es correcto.

Comment: Incrementa un contador dentro del `for`.

Answer (score 2):

El `wc` tendria que estar fuera del `for`:

```
for fichero in $(ls); do
    if [[ -f $fichero ]]; then
        echo $fichero
    fi
done | wc -l
```

Adicionalmente, no tienes que usar `ls`. Puedes hacer esto:

```
for fichero in *; do
```

El `*` bash lo reemplazaria por los archivos de donde estés parado.